# How to create a sub-table of another table with specific column entries in R?

Tags: r, data.table, subset, subtable

I have the following table `dT`:

```
structure(list(delivDate = structure(c(20489, 20500, 20516, 20517, 
20518, 20533), class = "Date"), priceDate = structure(c(19724, 
19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724), class = "Date"), priceIndex = c("KELAG HPFC DE", 
"HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", 
"HPFC DE"), avgPrice = c(109.65, 104.35, 104.5, 103.91, 
100.38, 76.57), quarters = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
```

Now, I have tried to create a new subset-table, which contains all columns of the origin table `dT`, but only these rows, which represents three specific `priceDate`-values.

I have tried the two following options, which both yield to an empty data table:

**1)**  `DT <- DT[priceDate %in% c("2024-01-02", "2024-03-05", "2024-03-12"), ]`

**2)** `base::subset(dT, (priceDate == '2024-01-02') & (priceDate == '2024-03-05') & (priceDate == '2024-03-12'))`

Both yield to the following Error: **Empty data.table (0 rows and 5 cols): delivDate,priceDate,priceIndex,avgPrice,quarters**.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:** This from a comment of @Soren works for my sample data:

```
dTNew <- dT[priceDate %in% as.Date(c("2024-01-02", "2024-03-05", "2024-03-12"))]
```

Comment: Try: DT[priceDate %in% as.Date(c("2024-01-02", "2024-03-05", "2024-03-12"))] or DT[as.character(priceDate) %in% c("2024-01-02", "2024-03-05", "2024-03-12")]

Comment: Your second expression is certain to fail, since `priceDate` cannot simultaneously be two or more values. I think that expression should be using the `|` "OR" operator instead of `&` "AND", though really the `%in%` method is preferred, whether in the `DT[...,]` or within `subset(DT, priceDate %in% c(..))`. FYI, your code works as intended for me. Also, typo, `dT` vs `DT`.

Comment: Usable data: `DT <- data.table::as.data.table(structure(list(delivDate = structure(c(20489, 20500, 20516, 20517), class = "Date"), priceDate = structure(c(19724.6, 19724.6, 19724.6, 19724.6), class = "Date"), priceIndex = c("HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE"), avgPrice = c(110, 104, 104, 104), quarters = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame")))`. It's a bit harder to test on data produced by the output of `str(.)`, please edit your question and add the output from `dput(head(DT))`. Thanks!

Comment: And after you post that updated sample data, please confirm your subsetting expressions _on that sample data_, and show that effort in a [code block]. It's not that I don't believe you, it's that this is difficult to use and reproduce, so it seems useful to look in other corners of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Soren: Thank you for your comment/answer. Your first idea with ``as.Date()`` already works fine. I didn't even think about it, since in the output of the table through ``str()``, ``priceDate`` was already labeled with **Date, format**.

Comment: @r2evans, I misunderstood ``&`` and ``|``. Ihave updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
library(data.table)

data <- structure(list(delivDate = structure(c(20489, 20500, 20516, 20517, 20518, 20533), class = "Date"),
                       priceDate = structure(c(19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724, 19724), class = "Date"),
                       priceIndex = c("KELAG HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE", "HPFC DE"),
                       avgPrice = c(109.65, 104.35, 104.5, 103.91, 100.38, 76.57),
                       quarters = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1", "Q1")),
                  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
                  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

specific_dates <- as.Date(c("2024-01-02", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03"))
subset_data <- data[priceDate %in% specific_dates]
```